# WebGL: INVALID_OPERATION: useProgram: program not valid

Tags: javascript, debugging, webgl

I'm learning WebGl and trying to convert a web mining script to do elliptical curve addition. I started by replacing the working GL code with the code from vanitygen-plus, even though it does more than I need/want. I also began replacing the variables passed to the expected ones and removed a bunch of unneeded JavaScript.
I now get the error "glminer.js:54 WebGL: INVALID_OPERATION: useProgram: program not valid" currently testing in chrome 91 on windows 10.
unfortunately this doesn't help me much as it doesn't tell me what is invalid.

```
        var program = gl.createProgram();
        vShader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
        gl.shaderSource(vShader,vShaderQuellcode);
        gl.compileShader(vShader);
        
            // Check for any compilation error
         if (!gl.getShaderParameter(vShader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
            console.log(gl.getShaderInfoLog(vShader));
        }
        gl.attachShader(program,vShader);
       gl.linkProgram(program);
        gl.useProgram(program); // error here
```

I would have posted shader-fs.js which is the code replaced from vanitygen-plus but it put me 7K char. over the limit

Comment: Where is the fragment shader?

Comment: honestly, I dont know as webgl is completly new to me. I only got started on this as I have a math problem I already coded in javascript but the bulk of it being repeated ECC point addition takes 24 hours to run on cpu @ 10K/sec while I saw vanitygen-plus does entire addresses at 3.5Million/sec on my gpu (aprox 350X speed up) the rest of my code only takes seconds to run on the selected results of the ECC addition.

Comment: The shader program cannot be linked, because the fragment shader is missing. `gl.linkProgram(program)` fails, therefore the shader program cannot be installed. This causes the _INVALID_OPERATION_ error in `gl.useProgram(program)`

Comment: having looked at your profile and seeing you have way more experience than myself with WebGl, do you know of any existing code that does what I'm after?  I also realized it doesn't have to be JavaScript, its just one of the very few languages i have any successful experience with.  the points I'm looking for are ones with an x value starting with certain bytes that are within a given distance(usually,1billion) from the start point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get more info on why your program is failing you can output the program info log. Add the following debugging code between linking and using the program:

```
gl.linkProgram(program);

// add this for extra debugging
if ( !gl.getProgramParameter( program, gl.LINK_STATUS) ) {
  var info = gl.getProgramInfoLog(program);
  throw new Error('Could not compile WebGL program. \n\n' + info);
}

gl.useProgram(program); // error here
```

Comment: thank you. this does add to my debugging capability. unfortunately I now know I don't have both shaders to make this work.at this point i dont even know if what i have is the Vertex or fragment shader.

Comment: `vShader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);` it's a vertex shader.

Comment: Here's a basic example using WebGL2 https://webgl2fundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-fundamentals.html

Comment: I think i found part of the problem, im just not sure how to deal with it. turns out the code from vanitygen-plus is opencl not GL.